# Is there gss/kerberos auth support on client side of apache mina sshd core version 1.3.0 release

Tags: java, kerberos, sshd, mina, gssapi

I have been using apache-mina-sshd to write a java ssh client to connect to an ssh server using kerberos[GSS/keytab] authentication. but i didn't find any useful resource to do it. Can any one say whether sshd support client side GSS authentication ?

Comment: Where did you find 1.3 version? There is latest 1.2: http://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/downloads.html To the question, it should support it: http://ssh-comparison.quendi.de/comparison/userauth.html

Comment: here : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sshd/sshd-core and in 1.2 when i went through i found out there is no support for client side gss authentication. look for auth packages in both server and client

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't support it in this version of sshd.